# How to filter array based on selected objects itself Java script

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to filter an array in Javascript by object value for the below example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

expected if I selected values

Start = 1;
End = 5;

Filtered array to be numbers between 1 to 5 

newArray1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

and if I selected the below values

```
Start= 6;
End= 9;
```

Expected to get this values
newArray2= [6,7,8,9];

```
NOTE: This need to be applied to use for clock hours and minutes to set schedule and durations and create booking slots.
```

Comment: object values? you want to filter by index range? 1 to 5 index?

Comment: You should read about [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that it is expected that you show your own attempts to solve your issue. Some simple research into how filtering works should have at least given you a start point. Then when your attempts don't work as expected you ask for help by presenting the code you tried

Comment: @charlietfk welcome to stack overflow. Note that it is expected that you don't completely harass people trying to ask completely valid questions. Some simple research into how to actually read English should have at least given you a starting point. Then when your attempts don't work as expected you ask for help by stop bothering people who are probably new to coding and don't know where else to ask, who have perfectly valid questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's built into modern day JavaScript

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
function getRange(x, start, end) {
    return x.filter(c=> c>= start&& c  <= end)
}

console.log(getRange(x, 1, 5), getRange(x,6,9))
```

Assuming your array has only number values

Answer (score 1):

comments inline

```js
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

// filter the arr based on start/end values
const filter = (arr, start, end) =>
  arr.filter((val) => val >= start && val <= end);
console.log(filter(x, 1, 5));
console.log(filter(x, 6, 9));

// if results need be based on indexes
const get = (arr, start, end) => arr.slice(start - 1, end);
console.log(get(x, 1, 5));
console.log(get(x, 6, 9));
```

Comment: Appreciated your support!